# Can't install Realtek ethernet driver on Debian 10

Tags: debian, drivers, firmware

I am a relatively inexperienced linux user, I used Mint before and now I'm trying Debian.
After configuring my interfaces I restarted my PC and while booting I noticed an error about network card firmware, and since there was only Windows on this machine before I figured I probably just need a linux driver for my card.

My problem is that I cannot install the driver I downloaded.
[image] When I try to run the shell script it stops because it can't find */lib/modules/4.19.0-10-amd64/build*.

[image]

Apparently I should have the dir here.

Am I supposed to have this dir by default?

I tried a few things but I'm really out of ideas.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try to install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you actually just need the [`firmware-realtek`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-realtek) package from [`non-free`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02#_debian_archive_basics).